# Convenient version overview of Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-data

I remember, long time ago, I saw an overview of what sub-project of Spring Data contributes in which version to the single release trains.

At the moment I can only infer this knowledge from the respective [BOM](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-build/blob/master/bom/pom.xml). I also could not find it anywhere on the [Spring Data project page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data).

Could anyone please point me to a convenient overview of past, current and maybe future release trains with their containing sub-project versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah just found that [wiki page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-planning) which holds a sidebar with all the yet-known release trains, for example [Release Train Moore](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Moore).
Maybe someone from the team could link to this location a little more prominent from the start page of Spring Data.